# Form filho fica na frente de tudo inclusive outras janelas Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Preciso que meus forms filho fiquem na frente do form pai, até ai blz. Só que eles ficam em cima de qualquer outra janela ou programa. Gostaria de saber se tem como os forms filho ficarem apenas na frente do forma pai e quando forem abertas outras janelas ou programas eles não ficarem na frente.

> Código que abre o form filho

```
  FormCadastroCliente formCli;
    private void BtnCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool _found = false;
        foreach (Form _openForm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (_openForm is FormCadastroCliente)
            {
                _openForm.Focus();
                _found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!_found)
        {
            formCli = new FormCadastroCliente();
            formCli.Show();
            formCli.BringToFront();
            formCli.TopMost = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tenta tirar o TopMost = true e deixa apenas BringToFront();

Comment: se a intenção é não deixar acessar o form pai, enquanto o filho estiver aberto, onde você abre o form filho, troque `formCli.Show();` por `formCli.ShowDialog();`

Comment: As duas sugestões já tentei, o que ocorre é se eu tiro o TopMost e clico no form pai o form filho cai atras, se eu trocar Show por showDialog enquanto um form filho estiver aberto não consigo clicar em nada no form pai.

Comment: e qual o objetivo afinal ?

Comment: O objetivo já alcançado: Abrir o form pai, depois disso abrir um ou mais Forms filho. os Forms filho ficarem sempre a frente do form pai mesmo clicando no form pai. Agora o principal objetivo: Quando estiver com um ou mais form filho já aberto e abrir uma pasta do windows por exemplo, quero que o form filho aberto fique atras da pasta aberta(oque não esta acontecendo) Os Forms filho ficam acima de tudo, tudo mesmo.

Comment: "enquanto um form filho estiver aberto não consigo clicar em nada no form pai" mas vc quer o form na frente do pai... como q vai clicar em alg coisa ?!  da mesma forma... se o filho tem que estar na frente do pai... como q vai abrir "um ou mais Forms filho"? ?

Comment: É uma sistema Rovann, eu posso abrir o cadastro de clientes e o mesmo tempo o de produtos. Do jeito que eu fiz esta funcionando como eu quero, só que os forms filho ficam na frente de tudo, qualquer janela, só quero resolver isso.

Comment: então cara... o comportamento dos forms é o mesmo de outras janelas do windows... ou ela é `TopMost` que vai ficar na frente de tudo... ou é `Modal` que "fica na frente de todas as janelas da aplicação, esperando uma resposta do usuário" ou é um form normal, e vai estar na frente o form ativo... há ainda o mdi child, mas acho que não se aplica ao caso

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/39wcs2dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396